# Oracle MAX function for SELECT statement against two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi there Oracle folks ,

I have two tables called book_items and  book_items_hist.

The join between the two tables is book_item_id.

In book_items, book_item_id is unique therefore there is only one book_item_id per record in the table.

In book_items_hist,  book_item_id is not unique, there are multiple book_item_id records in the table, for background reference, this is an history audit table.

I am trying to figure out how to use the MAX function to get me the latest record from book_items_hist b, the WHERE clause is on the b.book_timestamp.

However, the SQL below returns multiple rows from book_items_hist table and I am looking for a distinct results set.

```
Select a.book_item_id, a.book_sale_item_status, a.book_name  b.book_timestamp
from book_items  a
join  book_items_hist b  on a.book_item_id = b.book_item_id
group by a.book_item_id, a.book_sale_item_status, a.book_name, b.book_timestamp
having max(b.book_timestamp)  < (systimestamp - interval '10' minute)
```

Would appreciate some help along with an explanation/breakdown so that I can learn from this.

Thank You.

Comment: Please use sqlfiddle to show example data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `b.book_timestamp`--of course it will return multiple rows from `book_items_hist`, one per distinct `book_timestamp`. Remove this column from the grouping, and change your `SELECT` clause to `Max(b.book_timestamp)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want basically by removing the `book_timestamp` from the `group by` clause:

```
Select bi.book_item_id, bi.book_sale_item_status, bi.book_name, max(bih.book_timestamp)
from book_items bi join
     book_items_hist bih
     on bi.book_item_id = bih.book_item_id
group by bi.book_item_id, bi.book_sale_item_status, bi.book_name 
having max(b.book_timestamp)  < (systimestamp - interval '10' minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put your scaler function in you where clause. It's not necessary to use a group clause.

```
select a.book_item_id, b.book_sale_item_status,
a.book_name, b.book_timestamp from book_items a
join book_items_hist b on a.book_item_id = b.book_item_id where 
b.book_timestamp=(select max(book_timestamp) 
from book_items_hist where book_timestamp < systimestamp-interval '10' minute);
```

Another advantage of this approach is the performance compared to group function.

If you have any other filters on book_items_hist table, you should put them in to the inner scaler query for the sake of better performance. For example

```
select a.book_item_id, b.book_sale_item_status,
a.book_name, b.book_timestamp from book_items a
join book_items_hist b on a.book_item_id = b.book_item_id where 
b.book_timestamp=(select max(book_timestamp) 
from book_items_hist where book_timestamp < systimestamp-interval '10' minute 
and book_item_id=:1);
```